# Ubuntu 18.04 /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed

Tags: fan, temperature, lm-sensors

I am using ubuntu 18.04. Notebook 2am E550 With:

- Intel I5-9400
- Nvidia GTX 1050

I already have seem a lot of posts but none of them work.

### What I've done

1. Installed `lm-sensors`
2. I've run `sensors-detect` (as root) like this: `yes | sensors-detect`  https://pastebin.com/ZMruz1th
3. Finally pwmconfig (as root): `pwmconfig`

And i get the error: **`/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`**

4.I've tried adding to grub (and then rebooting): `acpi_enforce_resources=lax`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_enforce_resources=lax"
```

#### What I get when I run the `sensors` command

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +42.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +39.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +41.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +42.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +41.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +42.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +40.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Comment: `Found unknown chip with ID 0x8587` Not a lot of luck tracking that one down.  Do you have `/sys/class/thermal/` or `/proc/acpi/ibm/fan` present on the system?

Comment: Yeah I have `/sys/class/thermal/`. I tried to zip it but my notebook crashed. But if you need a information on a specif file i can search for it.

Comment: You should be able to use `thermald` to configure the fans.  Laptops don't often utilize pwm, but acpi instead.

Comment: I've installed (just installed) but i am not sure if its working, after having used for a while i realized that sometimes it still gets hot, did I forget something?

Comment: what temp is it at?  running `stress -c 8` I can easily get my laptop up to 80C before the fans kick on full blast, then it hovers around 60C.

Comment: after running `stress -c 8` and `sensors` the max temperature that I get is 88C. and the fans  kick on all. But there are any way to change the curve temperature/fan speed?

Comment: You could adjust the SamplingPeriod in /etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml, looks like the default is to check the temp every 12-16 seconds you could try and reduce that to see if it adjusts sooner.